# jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have a function that serves as a slideshow; the images change at the correct intervals, but do not have a fade animation:

```
function changePic() {
    if (n == pics.length) {
        pics = shuffleArray(pics);
        n = 0;
    }
    var pic = "media/" + pics[n];
    if (pic === "media/dave.png") {
        dave();
    }
    $("#dinner").fadeOut("slow",function(){
        $("#dinner").attr("src",pic);
        $("#dinner").fadeIn("slow",function(){
            setTimeout(changePic,slideDuration);
        });
    });
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Are any errors shown in the developer console? Can you share a working example on jsFiddle?

Comment: If you're updating the image `src`, you might need to [wait for it to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached) before fading it in.

Comment: here's the live site (complete with bugs) http://ukdinner.com

Comment: This still happens when all the images are local

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with fadeOut in both Chrome and IE10, but not Firefox 30.  The issue is apparently down to float:left - I removed that and the problem went away.  Not ideal, but according to the jQuery bug tracker, it's too low priority to fix.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7978

Answer (score 0):

`FadeIn()` and `FadeOut()` functions of Jquery does not support the basic version of Google Chrome(Version : 34). So, Please try updated version or try `show()` and `hide()`. It works good for me..

Answer (score -1):

try this :

instead of .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() try using **.show() and .hide()** that works good. Use this if animated effect is not important.